# numpy linear algebra basic help

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, svd

This is what I need to do-

I have this equation-

Ax = y

Where A is a rational m*n matrix (m<=n), and x and y are vectors of
the right size. I know A and y, I don't know what x is equal to. I
also know that there is no x where Ax equals exactly y.
I want to find the vector x' such that Ax' is as close as possible to
y. Meaning that (Ax' - y) is as close as possible to (0,0,0,...0).

I know that I need to use either the lstsq function:
http://www.scipy.org/doc/numpy_api_docs/numpy.linalg.linalg.html#lstsq

or the svd function:
http://www.scipy.org/doc/numpy_api_docs/numpy.linalg.linalg.html#svd

I don't understand the documentation at all. Can someone please show
me how to use these functions to solve my problem.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVD is for the case of m < n, because you don't really have enough degrees of freedom.

The docs for lstsq don't look very helpful.  I believe that's least square fitting, for the case where m > n.

If m < n, you'll want [SVD](http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm).

Comment: For a discussion of the SVD from a computing perspective, take a look at section 2.6 of the numerical recipes book (http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php)

Answer (score 2):

The [updated documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) may be a bit more helpful... looks like you want

```
numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, y)
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like x = numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, y) will solve your problem (and based on the return values it appears to solve the least-squares problem by using the SVD).  Beware that for m <= n, you are likely to suffer from overfitting, that is, you have enough degrees of freedom to fit y exactly, but only because your model is too flexible and is fitting the noise in addition to the underlying signal.

Answer (score 0):

The SVD of matrix A gives you orthogonal matrices U and V and diagonal matrix Σ such that

**A** = **U** **Σ** **V** <sup>T</sup>

where
**U** **U**<sup>T</sup> = **I** ;
**V** **V**<sup>T</sup> = **I**

Hence, if

**x** **A** = **y**

then

**x** **U** **Σ** **V** <sup>T</sup> = **y**

**x** **U** **Σ** **V** <sup>T</sup>  **V** = **y**  **V**

**x** **U** **Σ** = **y** **V**

**U** <sup>T</sup> **x** **Σ** =  **y** **V**

**x** **Σ** =  **U** **y** **V**

**x**  = **Σ** <sup>-1</sup> **U** <sup>T</sup>  **y** **V**

**x**  =  **V** <sup>T</sup> **Σ** <sup>-1</sup> **U** <sup>T</sup>  **y**

So given SVD of **A** you can get **x**.

---

Although for general matrices **A B** != **B A**, it is true for vector **x** that **x U** == **U** <sup>T</sup> **x**.

For example, consider **x** = ( x, y ), **U** = ( a, b ; c, d ):

**x** **U** = ( x, y ) ( a, b ; c, d )

= ( xa+yc, xb+yd )

= ( ax+cy, bx+dy )

= ( a, c; b, d ) ( x; y )

= **U** <sup>T</sup> **x**

It's fairly obvious when you look at the values in **x** **U** being the dot products of **x** and the columns of **U**, and the values in  **U**<sup>T</sup>**x** being the dot products of the **x** and the rows of **U**<sup>T</sup>, and the relation of rows and columns in transposition

Comment: In general matrix multiplication is not commutative, so in general xA != Ax.